# Why is the longest common subsequence for multiple strings NP-Hard?

Tags: string, algorithm, time-complexity, np

I'm having a tough time understanding why the longest common subsequence problem for multiple strings (k > 2) is NP-Hard. I know that the LCS problem for two strings of length l1, l2 can be solved in O(l1*l2) time. My question is why can't we find the LCS of two strings at a time, for example:

LCS(abcd, ad, abc) = LCS(LCS(abcd, ad), abc) = LCS(ad, abc) = a

This algorithm would take O(k*Max_length^2) for k strings. Why is this wrong?

Comment: Your first equal sign is wrong: LCS(eeeabcd, eeead, abc) != LCS(LCS(eeeabcd, eeead), abc) for instance

Comment: LCS(eeeabcd, eeead) = eeead, LCS(eeead, abc) = a, which is correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not generally true that LCS(x, y, z) = LCS(x, LCS(y, z)). For example:

> LCS(bb, aaabb, bbaaa) = bb
>
> LCS(bb, LCS(aaabb, bbaaa)) = LCS(bb, aaa) ≠ bb